# learn sharepoint from scratch

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I'm a .net developer. I want to learn SharePoint. There are a lot of resources online but don't know which one to get started with. SharePoint is for Users, Administrators and Developers, I am eager to learn the development part.

Comment: Start from Microsoft Developer Network (MSDN):

 "Find how-to content, sample code, SDK and API documentation, training, and technical articles for developing solutions and customizing SharePoint 2013.

 To find the developer content you want, browse the table of contents, use search, or click the links to some of the most popular areas of the technical content libraries. Content is organized by product, then by version, and then by reference type."

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj162979.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Would put as a comment but don't have enough reputation)

Don't have any special links or guides on hand however as a person who was/is in a position similar to you the way I went about learning was just diving in with an end goal in mind (a trial intranet with certain features, some I thought would be easy, some I thought would be hard) and when I ran into a problem looking up a solution online and trying different solutions to the same thing to figure out what works best for me.

A handy hint however is to make sure you back everything up regularly, especially when dealing with farm settings (I know you are not interested in the Admin side of things but you will still end up messing with the farm at some stage)

Answer (score 0):

Basics start from here [SharePoint 2013](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/sharepoint-2013-how-tos/) and [SharePoint Contents](http://sharepointquicksolutions.blogspot.in/) I used to learn a lot from here. You can read download SharePoint Foundation 2013 and explore it yourself